# How to remove incompatible extension of Firefox?

Tags: firefox

The Java extension was installed in the old version of Firefox, it become incompatible when Firefox updated. I want to remove it but there isn't a button for this operation. Is there any way to remove it or to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Console extension is installed globally via Windows Registry which is why the browser cannot "uninstall" it. It can however disable this extension which works just as well. So you should uninstall the old Java version via Control Panel / Add or Remove Programs (yes, it could happen that you have multiple Java versions installed on your computer). If that isn't the reason the best solution is not doing anything - the extension is disabled, it won't do any harm that way. If you *really* want to remove it, you can start the registry editor. The relevant entries can be found under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions
```

For reference: [Adding Extensions using the Windows Registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry).

Answer (score 1):

For uninstalling the unwanted extension:

1. From the Firefox window click on the Firefox button which is at the
   top left and select Add-ons, or, if the Firefox button is not shown,
   then click on the Tools menu and click Add-ons.
2. After the Add-on Manager has opened in a new tab, then click the Extensions button on the left side of the window.
3. Here you get the list of installed extensions on the right side together with buttons on the right side of each extension.
4. For Removing an extension from Firefox, simply click the Remove button. You should see a message that informs you about the
   successful removal of the add-on.
5. Please Note that some add-ons require a Firefox restart to remove completely. To perform a Firefox restart after the add-on removal,
   you need to click the Restart now link in the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Firefox on Windows, you could try to run it  in administrator mode and see if the option is allowed then.